# python code to find out if a password contains sequences

Tags: python, passwords, sequences, penetration-testing

For example a password may have the following sequences mentioned below. qwer,1234, 1qaz, qwe, qaz, qwer,
asd, asdf,wsx, wsx, 2wsx,wer, asdf , 1234, zxcv, 5678 . qwer, 1234, qa , qwe, qaz.how do I write a simple python code to see if a password given to contains the above mention sequences

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask questions.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582576/checking-a-string-for-adjacent-characters-on-the-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through and test if the text is in the password.  For example:

```
bad_strings = ["qwer", "1234", "1qaz", "qwe", "qaz", "qwer"]
passwords = ["blah347", "password1", "password2", "badqwer", "badqaz"]

def check_for_bad_password(password):
    for bad_string in bad_strings:
        if bad_string in password:
            return password

for password in passwords:
    if check_for_bad_password(password):
        print(password)
```

This prints out `badqwer` and `badqaz`